# Satipathanna sutta in audio English (long version)

Tags: reference-request, sutras, anapanasati, satipatthana

Can anyone direct me to the full audio version of the satipathanna sutta?

NOTE: I'm not looking for a guide or a talk just the plain sutta spoken clearly in English.

Comment: I you don't find one perhaps you can record one yourself easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [this](http://www.suttareadings.net/audio/mn.010.sclo.mp3) is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you. I've been memorising this one for awhile now. I can't always read so I like to listen during those times. However, I'm aware that mahasatipatthana seems to be more detailed than satipatthana. The former is what I meant when referring to the long version. I'm I right in thinking that mahasatipatthana is more detailed than satipatthana?

Comment: As far as I know both are the same, but I could be wrong.